# Problems with conversation bot example

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm having trouble trying to run the [Bot example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py) listed in the project folder of [this module](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)

Once I try run it I get these errors:

```
ReplyKeyboardRemove is not callable line 106
ReplyKeyboardRemove is not callable line 49
ReplyKeyboardMarkup is not callable line 39
```

and this in the console:

```
[Running] /usr/bin/env python "d:\Cartelle Importanti\Progetti\tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
Impossible to find specified path.
```

I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all other libraries installations for `TeleBot`, `Telethon` and etc. As a result you should have only `python-telegram-bot` in your `venv` with `telegram` package name.